# How can I restore the legacy metadata editor in iTunes 12?

Tags: itunes, music, metadata, itunes-u

**Question:** How can I restore the legacy metadata editor in iTunes 12?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Press and hold the  <kbd>⌥</kbd>  (option) key while clicking on **Get Info** for a given item.